# TypeError: loadshortlink() got multiple values for argument 'shortlink'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Error:
TypeError: loadshortlink() got multiple values for argument 'shortlink'

My urls.py:

```
path('s/<str:shortlink>',views.loadshortlink, name="get_longlink")
```

views.py:

```
def loadshortlink(shortlink):
    print("Translating short link %s" % shortlink)
    link = get_longlink(shortlink)
    return render(request, 'shortlinks/openlong.html', {
        'link': link

    })

def get_longlink(shortlink):
    print('Short link is %s' % shortlink)
    links = Links.objects.filter(shortlink=shortlink)
    if len(links)>1 or len(links)==1:
        link = links[0].longlink
        return link
    else:
        return 'No matched long links'
```

When I visit the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/s/4nI

I get the error:

```
Internal Server Error: /s/4nI
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: loadshortlink() got multiple values for argument 'shortlink'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument of view function should be request. You need to add it to `loadshortlink`:

```
def loadshortlink(request, shortlink):
    print("Translating short link %s" % shortlink)
    link = get_longlink(shortlink)
    return render(request, 'shortlinks/openlong.html', {
        'link': link

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not able to handle the request because loadshortlink method is missing request parameter. Your code should be:

```
def loadshortlink(request, shortlink):
    print("Translating short link %s" % shortlink)
    link = get_longlink(shortlink)
    return render(request, 'shortlinks/openlong.html', {
        'link': link

    })

def get_longlink(shortlink):
    print('Short link is %s' % shortlink)
    links = Links.objects.filter(shortlink=shortlink)
    if len(links)>1 or len(links)==1:
        link = links[0].longlink
        return link
    else:
        return 'No matched long links'
```